# Share embedded Facebook videos on Facebook with Open Graph

Tags: php, facebook, video

I have a website where I embed videos from Youtube, Dailymotion, Vimeo and Facebook. I would like that when a user shares the url of one of my website's page on Facebook, Facebook shows the video embed AND the video can play from inside Facebook.

I was able to achieve this for Vimeo, Youtube and Dailymotion videos : basically it's all about finding the right url to put in the og:video meta tag. For Youtube for instance :

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://www.youtube.com/v/videoID"/>

(+ add the secure_url and width and height tags)
```

I'm unable to get this to work for Facebook videos though. I have tried :

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://www.facebook.com/user/videos/videoid/"/>
```

which is the url you get when you right click on a Facebook video. But the video does not play with this url. I have found with the Video DownloadHelper Firefox plugin that there is an mp4 url behind each Facebook video: for instance https://video-cdg2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/13344433_966795020104719_2092907094_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjk5MCwicmxhIjo1MTIsInZlbmNvZGVfdGFnIjoidjNfNDI2X2NyZl8yM19tYWluXzMuMF9zZCJ9&rl=990&vabr=550&oh=fa35042783d265a37ead6003867c542b&oe=57ED3A8B

and it works if I use this url for the og:video tag, but I don't know how to generate this url with php from the Facebook video's ID.

Any idea on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Use the API to look up the details of the video by its id, the `source` field should hold the value you are looking for. (Although I am not sure if that URL is permanent, it might change at any time, which perhaps doesn’t make it that suitable to be used on OG meta tags.)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just call this URL from PHP to get video data

```
https://www.facebook.com/video/video_data/?video_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```